# Unable to import array library in Python

Tags: python, arrays, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, import

So I've started to learn Python recently and right now I've been trying to learn arrays, but unable to use the *array* function after importing the array library.

I have tried four different methods to use the array function but failed successfully.

**Method 1:**

```
import array
nums = array.array('i', [])
#rest of the code
```

*Output 1:*

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "array.py", line 2, in <module>
import array
File "/home/prince/Desktop/python-basics/array.py", line 
4, in <module>
nums = array.array('i', [])
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

**Method 2:**

```
import array as a
nums = a.array('i', [])
#rest of the code
```

*Output 2:*

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "array.py", line 2, in <module>
import array as a
File "/home/prince/Desktop/python-basics/array.py", line 
4, in <module>
nums = a.array('i', [])
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'array' has 
no attribute 'array' (most likely due to a circular 
import)
```

**Method 3:**

```
from array import array
nums = array('i', [])
#rest of the code
```

*Output 3:*

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "array.py", line 2, in <module>
from array import array
File "/home/prince/Desktop/python-basics/array.py", line 
2, in <module>
from array import array
ImportError: cannot import name 'array' from partially 
initialized module 'array' (most likely due to a circular 
import) (/home/prince/Desktop/python-basics/array.py)
```

**Method 4:**

```
from array import *
nums = array('i', [])
```

*Output 4:*

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "array.py", line 2, in <module>
from array import *
File "/home/prince/Desktop/python-basics/array.py", line 
4, in <module>
nums = array('i', [])
NameError: name 'array' is not defined
```

And after compilation, **every time** another folder is automatically created in my directory whose name is : ****pycache****

And inside that folder there is a file named: **array.cpython-38.pyc** which I am unable to open. My editor says that it is because it either uses binary or unsupported text.

A few additional details if that helps:

**Text Editor I Used:** *VS Code*

**My OS:**  *Ubuntu 20.04LTS*

**Python Version:** *3.8.5*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the above imports fail due to the file name being same as the module name which you import. Pretty sure you can't have the same name as the module you're trying to import. Try renaming the filename `array.py` to something else and it should work.

About pycache folder, it contains the compiled bytecode for the python program. This shouldn't have anything to do with this problem.